# "Does not refer to value" error in c++ procedural

Tags: c++, pointers, procedural

All of my errors are the exact same thing and I can't seem to figure out why. Any advice would be helpful. I have to use procedural c++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Elem {
    float Element;
}ELEM;

typedef struct Vector {
    unsigned int size = 0;
    Elem *numbers[];
}VECTOR;

// print_vec:
//  prints the vector array if it isn't NULL
// in:
//  RefToVector - single dimensional array of Elem's
// Out:
// Returns true if the array isn't NULL and it has something to print, NULL if otherwise
bool print_vec(Vector *numbers) {
    if (numbers != NULL) {
        printf("%f", numbers);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}

// *alloc_vec
// Allocates an empty vector array
// In:
//  Nothing
// Out:
// A newly allocated vector array

Vector *alloc_vec() {
    Vector *numbers = new Vector;
return numbers;
}

// dealloc_vec
// deallocates array
// In: 
//  an allocated array
// out: 
// Return: True if successfull, NULL if not

void dealloc_vec(Vector *numbers) {
    delete Vector *numbers;
}

// extend_vec
// Extends the vector by one element in size
// In:
// Vector array of x elements
// Out:
// Vector array of x + 1 elements
// Return: 
// A pointer to the new vector

Vector *extend_vec(Vector *numbers, Elem) {
    Vector *bigger = alloc_vec();
    bigger->size = numbers->size + 1; // set the size of the new vector to the size of the old plus one more element
    for (int i = 0; i <= numbers->size; i++) {
        bigger[i] = numbers[i]; // step through the vectors and copy the values
    }
    bigger[bigger->size-1] = Elem; // set last place in the new vector to the new element
    return bigger;
}


// scalar_plus
// Steps through the vector elements' and adds the same value to all of them
// In:
// Reference to a vector(array)
// Out: 
// Return: reference to vector with Elem value added to each

Vector *scalar_plus(Vector *numbers, Elem) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= numbers->size; i++){
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] + Elem;
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

My errors are all the same. and here they are

```
vecalc.cc:49:12: error: 'Vector' does not refer to a value
    delete Vector *numbers;
           ^
vecalc.cc:8:16: note: declared here
typedef struct Vector {
               ^
vecalc.cc:67:30: error: 'Elem' does not refer to a value
    bigger[bigger->size-1] = Elem; // set last place in the new vector t...
                             ^
vecalc.cc:4:16: note: declared here
typedef struct Elem {
               ^
vecalc.cc:64:23: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and
  'unsigned int' [-Wsign-compare]
    for (int i = 0; i <= numbers->size; i++) {
                    ~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
vecalc.cc:81:35: error: 'Elem' does not refer to a value
        numbers[i] = numbers[i] + Elem;
                                  ^
vecalc.cc:4:16: note: declared here
 typedef struct Elem {
                ^
vecalc.cc:98:4: error: 'Vector' does not refer to a value
                *Vector = *alloc_vec();
                 ^
vecalc.cc:8:16: note: declared here
typedef struct Vector {
               ^
vecalc.cc:99:11: error: 'Vector' does not refer to a value
                assert(&Vector == NULL)
                        ^
vecalc.cc:8:16: note: declared here
typedef struct Vector {
               ^
vecalc.cc:103:14: error: 'Vector' does not refer to a value
                print_vec(*Vector);
                           ^
vecalc.cc:8:16: note: declared here
typedef struct Vector {
               ^
```

and because they are all the same I'm sure if I figure out how to fix one I'll get them all..

Comment: You're using structure names where you're supposed to put variables. You need to learn the difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show even the most basic research.

Comment: It is actually rather good written question. I agree that this is elementary thing, but the code is clearly written and even clearly commented. If every question with quality lower than this one was closed there would stay just a few dozen questions a day.

Comment: It may or may not be worth pointing out that "I have to use procedural c++.", is a ridiculous statement. And you shouldn't be encouraged to write quote on quote procedural c++, that said, (i'm guessing at your tutors definition of procedural), this isn't even procedural code.

Comment: @Rasty: It's a pretty poorly written question, actually. Inconsistent code formatting, no clear problem statement (e.g. which line of code fails), incomprehensible phrases (*"procedural C++"*), and most importantly, it is neither complete nor minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The compilor is telling you, you are using the **type** name in places where **variable name** should be. 
So for example for the first error there should be just `delete numbers;` there are also places where you are straight missing the variable name and having only types where both or only the variable name should be.